# How to redirect to caller controller action

Tags: model-view-controller, internationalization

I'm implementing this internationalization tutorial. However when I set the culture on one controller it redirects me back to the homepage. Anyone know how to stay on the same page? https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I got it! Changed the redirect in the SetCulture ActionResult to

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```